# How to build a sql query to get 100 rows belonging to weekday(Mon-Fri) from a table using epoch time column

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, epoch

I want query a oracle sql database to get 100(this number can increase 10x) rows belonging to weekday (Mon-Fri) using epoch time column. Query will be executed from a spring boot application. What is the approach for building the logic & query for this requirement?
Consider below table for example. The day for A & B both falls on Thursday(i.e weekday) But C falls on Saturday when the epoch time is converted. (acc to GMT time.).
Hence the output must be the rows A & B.

| Name | time_c. |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1674086400 |
| B | 1673481600 |
| C | 1673049600 |

I was checking if the sql `TO_CHAR()` function can some how be used after converting the epoch time to date but I'm not sure how the filter can be applied within the query.

Comment: Which query-framework are you using? JPA?

Comment: @Z-100  Using JDBC

Comment: What is the data type of your column? An integer type? Or a date-time type?

Comment: By what time zone do you want to determine the date? For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Did you want the date as seen in UTC (GMT)? Your question mentions GMT, but is not clear.

Comment: @BasilBourque data type of the time_c column is NUMBER. Time zone required would be GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Oracle is concerned, here's one option.

(setting date format just to show *what is what*; you don't have to do that)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name, time_c) as
  2    (select 'A', 1674086400 from dual union all
  3     select 'B', 1673481600 from dual union all
  4     select 'C', 1673049600 from dual
  5    ),
```

Query *converts* `time_c` to a `date` datatype value (`datum` column) and - additionally - finds which day it was (the `dan` column). Then, exclude weekends and fetch as many rows as you want (line #16):

```
  6  temp as
  7    (select name, time_c,
  8       date '1970-01-01' + time_c / 86400 datum,
  9       to_char(date '1970-01-01' + time_c / 86400, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') dan
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select name, time_c, datum, dan
 13  from temp
 14  where dan not in ('sat', 'sun')
 15  order by datum desc
 16  fetch first 100 rows only;

N     TIME_C DATUM      DAN
- ---------- ---------- ------------
A 1674086400 19.01.2023 thu
B 1673481600 12.01.2023 thu

SQL>
```

That piece of code can be rewritten to a function that returns e.g. refcursor or whatever you find appropriate so that you could use it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 days a week and 1970-01-01 is a Thursday, so if we start counting from 1970-01-01 in 7-day periods (where 1970-01-01 is the 0th day of the week) then the weekends are the 2rd and 3th days (again zero-indexed) of each week.

You can use that to exclude the weekends using only arithmetic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  MOD(time_c, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60) <  2 * 24 * 60 * 60
OR     MOD(time_c, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60) >= 4 * 24 * 60 * 60
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```